# css won't center inside div ?

Tags: css, center

So, I am trying to center this button inside the DIV.

the button is a  a href link...

here is an example....

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6WJSp/)

I always thought I could just set the margin 0 auto and it would work but I guess not.

It used to work? I am not sure what i am doing wrong

```
<div style="background-color:#0F0; width:100%; height:100px; display:block;"> 


                <div style=" width:50%; margin:0 auto;"><a style="margin:0px;"class="btn btn-3 btn-3d icon-cog">Settings</a></div>

                   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="center"><a class="btn btn-3 btn-3d icon-cog">Settings</a></div>

.center{text-align:center;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/6WJSp/1/)

Comment: I wonder why the block element would not center it properly...

though if i used display table for the first div and then make the button to display: table-cell it worked. weird

Comment: @op1001 because its `width` is not defined. Hence, it takes 100% width. Leaving no space for margin.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the display to block for it to work

```
#button {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <div style="background-color:#0F0; width:100%; height:100px;"> 


                <div style=" width:50%; margin:0 auto;"><a class="btn btn-3 btn-3d icon-cog">Settings</a></div>

                   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* General button style (reset) */
.btn {
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    margin:0;
}

.btn:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* Pseudo elements for icons */
.btn:before,
.icon-heart:after,
.icon-star:after,
.icon-plus:after,
.icon-file:before {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.icon-envelope:before {
    content: "\e000";
}

.icon-cart:before {
    content: "\e007";
}

.icon-cart-2:before {
    content: "\e008";
}

.icon-heart:before {
    content: "\e009";
}

/* Filled heart */
.icon-heart:after,
.icon-heart-2:before {
    content: "\e00a";
}

.icon-star:before {
    content: "\e00b";
}

/* Filled star */
.icon-star:after,
.icon-star-2:before {
    content: "\e00c";
}

.icon-arrow-right:before {
    content: "\e00d";
}

.icon-arrow-left:before {
    content: "\e003";
}

.icon-truck:before {
    content: "\e00e";
}

.icon-remove:before {
    content: "\e00f";
}

.icon-cog:before {
    content: "\e010";
}

.icon-plus:before,
.icon-plus:after {
    content: "\e011";
}

.icon-minus:before {
    content: "\e012";
}

.bh-icon-smiley:before {
    content: "\e001";
}

.bh-icon-sad:before {
    content: "\e002";
}

.icon-file:before {
    content: "\e004";
}

.icon-remove-2:before {
    content: "\e005";
}


/* Button 3 */
.btn-3 {
    background: #fcad26;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-3:hover {
    background: #f29e0d;
}

.btn-3:active {
    background: #f58500;
    top: 2px;
}

.btn-3:before {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 3;
    font-size: 140%;
    width: 60px;
}

/* Button 3d */
.btn-3d {
    padding: 15px 60px 15px 70px;
}

.btn-3d:before {
    background: #fff;
    color: #fcad26;
    z-index: 2;
    line-height:51px;
}

.btn-3d:after {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 55px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.btn-3d:active:before {
    color: #f58500;
}

.btn-3d:active {
    top: 0;
}

.btn-3d:active:after {
    left: 60px;
}


.icon-cog:before {
font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    content: "\f02d";
}
.center{text-align:center;}
```

[Updated Fiddle of your's](http://jsfiddle.net/6WJSp/6/)